# java. Распаковать вложенные чередующиеся архивы zip/tar в количестве > 2000 шт

Tags: java, рекурсия, zip, tar

Дан архив в котором запакован еще архив и тд. 2000 раз. Архивы чередуются zip/tar.
Необходимо добраться до конечного файла.
Как распаковать tar без загрузки и подключения библиотеки для чтения tar?
Решаю на java. Zipinputstream не распаковывает tar. Пришлось подключать библиотеку Apache Commons Compress, но наверняка есть более рациональный способ.
Естественно, в основе решения лежит рекурсия, но вопрос не об этом.

Comment: Добавьте в сам вопрос больше информации. Как пытались решить, что не получается, какие инструменты используете, какие можно использовать и проч.

Comment: у голого tar'а очень простой формат... если не хочешь использовать библиотеки можешь распаковать его ручками...

Comment: Более рациональный способ - это сделать простенький шел скрипт в цикле распаковывающий архив посредством обычных утилит.